# Python : Function to pull a sound clip from URL and save it in local machine

Tags: python

Would like to create a function that pulls a sound from given url and saves it in my machine locally

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 2):

use urllib module

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(url,sound_clip_name)
```

the file will be save as what you provide the name

alternative, using urllib2

```
import urllib2
file = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
f = open('sound_clip','w')
f.write(file)
f.close()
```

don't forget to give the extension of your file

Answer (score 0):

If in Python 2.7, urllib2 module is your friend, or urllib.request in Python3.

Example in 2.7 :

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')

with open(filename, w) as fd:
    fd.write(f.read)
```